# How can I delay a loop depending on a condition?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a delay in a loop depending on a condition. Say, I have this:

```
var maxLoops = 50;
var counter = 0;

(function next() {
    if (counter++ >= maxLoops) {
      return;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(counter);
        next();
    }, 100);
})();
```

Is there any way to pause the process for 2 seconds only when the counter is equal to 10, 20 or 30? So it should print:

```
 1....10 
 (delay for a custom period of time)
 11....20
 (delay for a custom period of time)
 21....30
 (delay for a custom period of time)
 31...50
```

The bottom line is, I don't want to delay at all when the counter isn't equal to 10, 20, 30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can do that just change the timeout when you have a multiple of 10.

```
var maxLoops = 50;
var counter = 0;

(function next() {
    counter += 1
    var timeout_duration = counter % 10 == 0 ? 2000 : 0;

    if (counter >= maxLoops) {
      return;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(counter);
        next();
    }, timeout_duration);
})();
```

That said, there need some few improvments because maxLoops and counter are defined on the global scope. Make it a function.

```
function loop (maxLoops, start) {
    var counter = start || 0;

    (function next() {
        counter += 1
        var timeout_duration = counter % 10 == 0 ? 2000 : 100;

        if (counter >= maxLoops) {
          return;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(counter);
            next();
        }, timeout_duration);
    })();
}

loop(50);
```

If you don't want to call `next` when counter isn't a multiple of 10, then you can add a usual loop in between the calls.

```
function loop (maxLoops, start) {
    var counter = start || 0;
    var timeout_duration = 2000;

    (function next() {
        while(counter < maxLoops && counter % 10 != 0) {
          counter += 1
        }

        if (counter >= maxLoops) {
          return;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(counter);
            next();
        }, timeout_duration);
    })();
}

loop(50);
```

That said, keep in mind that a `setTimeout` of `2000` doesn't mean exactly 2 seconds, but not less than 2 seconds. If somehwere, there is a loop that breaks the thread, the `setTimeout` could be never called as Javascript is single threaded and there is no fact that the function will be called after 2 seconds. If you're planning to use `setTimeout` to measure something within time, you might have to plan something else that will include the `Date` object for timings.

Comment: do we need setTimeout at all when the delay is zero, can't we call next() directly?

Comment: it's better to call `setTimeout` because if you call `next()` directly, you could have a stackoverflow, Javascript doesn't have tail recursive call optimization, so if you're going to recurse a lot, it will break at some point. In your case, it could work, because you'll have a maximum of 10 recursion each time. But if you were checking each 100000000, it wouldn't work I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `setTimeout()` with a different timing based on your counter:

```
var maxLoops = 50;
var counter = 0;

(function next() {
    if (counter++ >= maxLoops) {
      return;
    }
    var delay = 0;
    // on multiples of 10, use a longer counter
    if (counter % 10 === 0) {
        delay = 2000;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(counter);
        next();
    }, delay);
})();
```

Or, you could skip the `setTimeout()` completely when you don't need the delay.

```
var maxLoops = 50;
var counter = 0;

(function next() {
    if (counter++ >= maxLoops) {
      return;
    }
    // on multiples of 10, use a longer counter
    if (counter % 10 === 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(counter);
            next();
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        console.log(counter);
        next();
    }
})();
```

Or, rather than recursion, you can just use a while loop as in this working snippet:

```js
var maxLoops = 50;
var counter = 0;

(function next() {
    // while we haven't hit maxLoops and while not a multiple of 10
    while (counter < maxLoops && counter % 10 !== 0 && counter !== 0) {
        log(counter);
        ++counter;
    }
    if (counter < maxLoops) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            log(counter);
            ++counter;
            next();
        }, 1000);
    }
})();

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("span");
    div.innerHTML = x + " ";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: the thing is, I don't want to delay at all when the counter isn't equal to 10, 20, 30.

Comment: You need to increment counter in the while loop. It will loop infinitely this way.